# Oracle not allow to grant on sys.*

Tags: oracle, sql-grant

I'm running an installer script. which is granting on `sys.aux_stats$`, `sys.wri$optstat_aux_history`, `sys.dbms_spm` and `sys.dbms_xplan`. At this point there is an exception throwed: `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges` For the installer I created a DBA-User (`FOODBA`) and a DB-User (`FOOADM`). The DBA is created like this on the oracle machine:

```
bash-4.1$ sqlplus
...
Enter user-name: sys as sysdba
Enter password:
SQL> CREATE USER FOODBA IDENTIFIED BY Password;
User created.
SQL> GRANT DBA TO FOODBA ;
Grant succeeded.
SQL> GRANT ADMINISTER SQL MANAGEMENT OBJECT TO FOODBA ;

Grant succeeded.
```

doesn't work at all, do I tried like this:

```
SQL> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO FOODBA;
Grant succeeded.
```

Still not working, so I tried to give permission on custom object:

```
SQL> grant all privileges on sys.aux_stats$ to FOODBA;

Grant succeeded.
```

And when I run the script with user `FOODBA`:

```
grant select, insert, update, delete on sys.aux_stats$ to FOOADM
```

It's throwing again the `insufficient privileges` excpetion.

What I'm supposed to do, so that the `FOODBA` user can create and grant the `FOOADM` correctly? The install script is 3rd party.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having an object grant is not sufficient to pass this grant on to another user/role. You will need "with grant option".

```
grant select, insert, update, delete on sys.aux_stats$ to FOODBA with grant option;
```

Comment: `grant select, insert, update, delete on sys.aux_stats$ to FOOADM with grant option;`
throws `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`
Do I need to enable more power for the `FOODBA`?

Comment: You need to be sys and grant this to FOODBA. Then FOODBA can grant select to FOOADM.